# Mapping using Expression Trees? Is it possible to implement this?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

```
public static MapFrom Map(this IDataReader idr, params string[] columns)
{
     return new MapFrom { Columns = columns };
}
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> To<TEntity>(this MapFrom from, Func<TEntity, object> map)
{
     // logic here.
}    

public IEnumerable<FooEntity> Execute()
{
    using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetListOfFoo"))
    {
        using (IDataReader idr = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
            return idr.Map("FooID", "FooOfPooAmount", "AnotherFooColumn", "BarID")
              .To<FooEntity>(x => new object[]{
                          x.FooID, x.FooOfPooAmount, x.AnotherFoo, x.BarID
            });
         }
     }
}
```

I wish to take a data reader and create a simple mapper that is easy to use and is also performant. I haven't used expression trees much, but I feel like they may be needed. What I want to do is inspect the *relationship* of  x to it's array (The lambda expression), and then use this relationship to automatically map values appropriately and create a new List of Foo Entitiies.

MapFrom is just a container to carry information and allow fluent extension methods.

The point of these acrobatics is to have a simple way to specify relationships. I realize I could easily do something like in a different form, but I wanted to be able to list columns "fluently" [1] (as in typing column name as a string followed by comma then next column name) and then list the object properties in sequential order and infer the mapping from this. It it possible to implement the **To** method above? Are Expression Trees appropriate here? I figure I can easily enough infer type casting for the data reader fields from the FooEntity property types.

[1] In this context I do not mean fluent as in "Fluent API"

Comment: Why you want to reinvent the wheel? :)
You're starting to write an ORM, it's not a good idea.

Comment: ORMs I am familiar with are too heavy weight. I want something very light weight and close to the same as hand-rolling - just with redundancy and unnecessary noise removed. ORMs I have seen have undesirable constraints - performance, SQL mixed in with C# logic, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote here your *MapFrom* class, than you have to write the code to copy the value from columns to the property of an instance of FooEntity and use the `yield return` statement to return a collection of your entity, so add another method to the *MapFrom* class:

```
public class MapFrom
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> columnMapDictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public MapFrom(string[] columns)
    {
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            columnMapDictionary.Add(column, null);
        }
    }

    public void To<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
    {
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var columnMap in columnMapDictionary.ToDictionary(k => k.Key))
        {
            var member = (properties[index++].Body as MemberExpression);
            var propertyName = member.Member.Name;
            columnMapDictionary[columnMap.Key] = propertyName;  
        }
    }
}
```

Use it as:

```
var mapper = new MapFrom("Name", "Surname");
mapper.To<FooEntity>(p => p.FirstName, p => p.LastName);
```